# Synplify: Asynchronous load of non-constant data for foo is not supported

Tags: asynchronous, vhdl, reset, synthesis

While trying to compile and synthesise my VHDL design using Synplify Pro (Lattice edition), I get the following errors and warnings:

```
Asynchronous load of non-constant data for counter(0) is not supported
Input data for signal counter(31 downto 0) contains references to signal edges. An asynchronous reset may be missing from the sensitivity list.
```

The first error is CL126 and is described in the manual as 'The HDL code contained an incomplete description of an asynchronous load on a sequential element.'

The second line is a warning (CL116), but is not found in the manual and google comes up empty as well.

What I gather from this is that somehow Synplify fails to infer that an asynchronous reset is being used, though I get the first error for other lines as well without the warning provided for the same line.

The block containing the cnt/counter variable and signal (integer):

```
receive_counter : process (reset, receive_add, receive_rst) 
    variable cnt        : integer;
begin
    if reset = '1' or receive_rst'event then
        cnt     := -1;
        counter <= -1;
    elsif receive_add'event then
        cnt     := cnt + 1;
        counter <= cnt;
    end if;
end process;
```

The reset signal is propagated from the top-level design down to a lower-level design file which contains multiple modules, each of which contain this same logic which it complaints about for this singular module. I have not been able to ascertain why Synplify treats this module different from the others.

I already looked into reset distribution trees and related, thinking that it might help me, but I'm not entirely certain that this is where the cause of this problem lies. Maybe anyone here has a clue, or has at least seen this error and warning before from Synplify?

Comment: `elsif receive_add'event then` is problematic : pick an edge! For example, `elsif rising_edge(receive_add) then` ... but this may not be your problem. Probably `receive_rst'event` is.

Answer (score 2):

There are two valid patterns for implementing a reset in any synthesis tool I have used. Obviously the edge (rising or falling) can be changed, as can the polarity of reset:

```
process (reset, clk)
begin
  if (reset = '1') then
    q <= '0'; -- or '1'
  elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
    q <= d;
  end if;
end process;
```

or

```
process (clk)
begin
  if (rising_edge(clk)) then
    if (reset = '1') then
      q <= '0';
    else
      q <= d;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

What you are trying to describe is a register that is sensitive to *both edges* edges on *two different clocks*, and a register of this kind does not exist in the FPGA fabric. You need to come up with a design that only uses registers that are sensitive to *one* clock.

---

Regarding the error:

> Asynchronous load of non-constant data for counter(0) is not supported

If you take a look at the manual for your FPGA, you should find a detailed description of exactly what logic resources are available, and exactly what the registers in the device can do. Normally these might have a data input, an enable, and an asynchronous control that can be set at configuration time to either set *or* clear the register. I can't see that the code you posted is actually doing what the error message says, but what you cannot have in any FPGA device I have used is to have an asynchronous *load*. This would appear to be what that particular error message is saying. When I have accidentally made this mistake before, the tools have inferred a latch, which is undesirable. As above, the following code should map to what is available in the FPGA:

```
process (reset, clk)
begin
  if (reset = '1') then
    q <= '0'; -- or '1'
  elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
    q <= d;
  end if;
end process;
```

however this code would not, if there is no asynchronous load capability in the fabric registers (as there is unlikely to be in your device):

```
process (reset, clk)
begin
  if (reset = '1') then
    q <= d2;  -- Async load
  elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
    q <= d;
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: An acquaintance suggested that my problem is that the FPGA fabric doesn't support DDR flip-flops, which makes sense because of the 'event usage. This seems to jive with your answer as well. A possible solution then may be to implement DDR FFs in VHDL, so that the synthesiser can use regular FFs to simulate the desired behaviour.

Comment: @MayaPosch your code does not describe a DDR flip flop. Inference of DDR elements is not generally supported by synthesis tools anyway. As I said, you need to create a design that uses registers based on the patterns in my answer. If you try to simulate DDR registers you will be going against conventional design techniques and will likely end up with a more complicated design than if you were to simply work with the available patterns.